# SSL Handshake Error while connecting to Server via web client

Tags: python, ssl, mdm

I am using SSL Connection from Web Client (firefox) to connect to the local Server created via the code available in this link [MDM server code](https://github.com/intrepidusgroup/imdmtools/blob/master/Tools/server/server.py) I have all the required signed Certificates issued by Apple available for running the server, as well as all the depended python modules installed.

I ran my code using the following command on my Windows Machine.
python server.py .
This successfully start running the server at the port 8080.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MDMServer>python server.py <ip address>
Can't find MyApp.mobileprovision in current directory.
Need both MyApp.ipa and Manifest.plist to enable InstallCustomApp.
Starting Server
https://<ipaddress>:8080/
```

But whenever a Web Client tries to connect to this Server.

Upon launching the link `https://<ip address>:8080` in the firefox. The Server reports the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 498, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 313, in run
    return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgi.py", line 54, in runwsgi
    return httpserver.runsimple(func, validip(listget(sys.argv, 1, '')))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\httpserver.py", line 157, in runsimple

    server.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgiserver\__init__.py", line 1765, in
 start
    self.tick()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgiserver\__init__.py", line 1815, in
 tick
    s, ssl_env = self.ssl_adapter.wrap(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgiserver\ssl_builtin.py", line 42, i
n wrap
    keyfile=self.private_key, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 372, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 296, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_
HELLO:no shared cipher
```

Can anyone help me understand:

1) What these errors mean

2) Why I'm getting them, It was not coming with the older version of server.py code applicable to iphone 4s?

3) How I can go about fixing these

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

This is because APNSWrapper hasn't been updated to TLSv1 yet.

Apple no longer supports sslv3 for MDM due to the POODLE vulnerability.

You can update APNSWrapper source yourself though pretty easily.

download the source and update connection.py

```
ssl_version = self.ssl_module.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
```

the run

```
python setup.py install
```